# Add 3D Touch Quick Actions from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift

This is how my app is structured.

```
MainViewController (UITabViewController) --> VC1 (UIViewController) --> AddVC (UIViewController)  
                                         --> VC2 (UIViewController)  
                                         --> VC3 (UIViewController)
```

I want to add quick actions to my app, so I can access the `AddVC` when I press the action button from `AppDelegate`.
`VC1` has an Add button which uses a segue to go to `AddVC`.

This is how I am trying to do: create the `AddVC` view controller and then `MainViewController` and from this I retrieve the `VC1` with which I try to present the `AddVC` screen.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performActionFor shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddVC") as! AddVC

    switch shortcutItem.type {
    case "Add":
        let mainVC = app?.getRootViewController() as! MainViewController
        let vc1 = mainVC.getVC1()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            vc1?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
}
```

When I do this, it always go to `VC1` view controller, but not to the `AddVC`, so the segue is not performed.
I also tried using `performSegue` inside the `DispatchQueue`, same effect.

Anyone has an idea how can I make this work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing this is a timing issue.

The hacky way to test is just to delay your `Dispatch` for a second (or however long it takes your app to launch) and see if it works then.

A better solution would be to add a `shouldGoToAddVC` flag to `VC1` and do your `present` after `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. My app is already started. I just exit it and 3D touch on icon and press my button. I am not sure why there is a timing issue.

Comment: Because VC1 isn't on the screen yet. Until the app's full activation completions and the animation from your home screen the the app completes, it won't be able to navigate to a new VC. Also keep in mind that your app may not be alive whatsoever when a quick action takes place.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I added a sleep(3) and I get this warning: Attempt to present <AddVC: 0x10206a400> on <VC1: 0x101e24250> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: Sounds like VC1 wasn't on screen

Comment: Yep, I tried your solution, but instead of viewDidAppear, I need a custom notificaiton for when app will enter foreground, because viewDidAppear will not get called in my case. Still the issue is, that the event is called before I set the flag from AppDelegate.

Comment: Did you test it? AFAIK `viewDidAppear` should be called when you come from background.

Comment: I test it, it doesn't. I also search on the internet, viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear will not get called when the app goes to background and comes back to foreground.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157030/discussion-between-peejweej-and-kobe).

Comment: Huh...I guess I'm crazy 0:-) registering for `UIApplicationWillEnterForeground` will probably do what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25716012/triggering-a-specific-action-when-the-app-enters-foreground-from-a-local-notific

Comment: Yeah, I already use that notification, but the issue is, when my app enters foreground, this event is triggered and only after this, the AppDelegate code is called where I set the flag to true. So at the time, the enter foreground event is fired, the flag is still false.