# OneSignal: How to send push notification only if app is active?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, onesignal

I am using push api from OneSignal.com to send notifications. It's working perfectly but I want to receive notifications only if app is Active. If app is closed or not active then Onsignal notifications should be stopped.

Is this possible with this service?

I'll really appreciate for any contribution.

Thanks

Comment: Check `[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState` for `UIApplicationStateActive` http://stackoverflow.com/a/8292048/4488635

Comment: I am using cordova. How can I use above code? I can write only javascript.

Comment: Push notifications are designed to reach users when they are not activity using your app. In your case it sounds like you are looking for local notifications.

Answer (score 0):

You does not send push notification on active user however you have send notification using creating segment with adding filter last session time.